# Area 51 Discussion Zone - How will these be actioned?

Tags: discussion, area-51

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How will the Area51 discussion proceed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77918/how-will-the-area51-discussion-proceed)

I've had a chance to have a good look around the Discussion Zone on Area 51 today and I think it is a good idea. I have also read through the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/area-51-gets-organized-lets-talk/) announcing the Discussion Zone.

Towards the bottom of that post is this graphic:

[image]

What I would like to know is how these things 'Merge' and 'Delete' are going to be actioned? At the moment there [are](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/merge-sports-proposals) [several](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/merge-garding-and-farming-organically-with-garding-landscaping-call-it-ga) [discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/merging-all-music-proposals) (the top 3 by votes) asking about merging.

It's fine to create extra discussion around these, but if there is no way to reach a consensus or to action the ideas it's only creating more noise and in some cases [more frustration](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/merge-garding-and-farming-organically-with-garding-landscaping-call-it-ga/129#129).

Will we have any way in the near future to put actions to the discussions?