# Auto-suggest [change-request] tag

Tags: feature-request, area-51

Many proposals on Area51 have discussions about merges.  Almost all of these discussions should have the [change-request](/questions/tagged/change-request) tag, and most should start out with the [status-review] tag as well, as per this post:

[How will the Area 51 discussion proceed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77918/how-will-the-area-51-discussion-proceed/78030#78030)

> *Many* of the discussions in Area 51 can be handled by the community processes (vote to close, etc). But proposals that need manual intervention (merges, etc) will be considered and handled much like [feature-requests] and [bugs] in meta.
>
> #### The `[change-request]` Tag
>
> Discussions *start out* as proposal-building activities. But if the discussion concludes that external intervention is needed, **it should be tagged as a `[change-request]`** (I will be re-tagging the previous discussions, but feel free to start using this tag now).

Users haven't started using it, probably because they don't know about it.  Therefore, at the very least, it should be added to the "How To Ask" sidebar. See the [[tag:merging]](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merging) tag: 11 of the 15 newest questions (the past 5 days) don't have it. It's not being used.

I also propose that the [change-request](/questions/tagged/change-request) tag should be suggested when the word "merge" (or other related words) is detected in a discussion. If this tag suggestion feature is implemented, it might be nice to also suggest a proposal link or category while you're at it.

Comment: @downvoters - Care to explain why this is a bad idea?  Is my initial premise (discussions about merging should have the change-request tag) incorrect?  I softened that language a little.